# Python Merge duplicates, sum and multiply

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have the BoM list below Where the first column are the Materials, the second column is the Quantity, and the third column, the unit Cost.
I need to merge duplicates, sum the values in the second column and third column, and multiply the third column with the second to get the final cost.

```
['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0]
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0]
['Material 2', 4.0, 8.0]
['Material 3', 6.0, 36.0]
['Material 4', 4.0, 16.0]
```

So, i started searching and i thought i found a solution with Pandas, to merge the duplicate Materials and to sum the second column duplicates as well as the third column duplicates. I thought it could be a start...:

```
BoM1 = pd.DataFrame([BoM],columns=['Component', 'Qty', 'Cost'])
BoM2 = BoM.groupby(['Component'],as_index=False).agg({'Qty': 'sum'},{'Cost': 'sum'})
print(BoM2)
```

But i got this messed result:

```
['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0]
        Component  Qty
0  Material 1  1.0
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
        Component  Qty
0  Material 2  2.0
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
        Component  Qty
0  Material 3  3.0
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0]
        Component  Qty
0  Material 2  2.0
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0]
        Component  Qty
0  Material 3  3.0
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]
        Component  Qty
0  Material 4  4.0
```

Any ideas how i can fix it?

Comment: Can you explain the math/logic in your expected third column results?

Comment: Sure. I need to find all the materials i need to buy from a list of products. Every product has a bill of materials, and some materials are duplicate. So i have a list of materials, the quantity, and unit cost. I have to merge the duplicates, sum the quantities and to find the total cost of those materials. To resume, i need to sum the quantities of duplicates first, then i need to sum the unit cost. Finally, i need to multiply the unit cost with the material quantities, to give me the total cost for those materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your weird output is that you are using `groupby` on `BoM` rather than `BoM1`. You can get the result you want by creating a new column, `Total` as the product of `Qty` and `Cost` and then summing that column. Note you have a syntax issue in the parameter to `.agg`, it should be a single dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

BoM = [['Material 1', 1.0, 1.0],
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0],
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0],
['Material 2', 2.0, 2.0],
['Material 3', 3.0, 3.0],
['Material 4', 4.0, 4.0]]

BoM1 = pd.DataFrame(BoM,columns=['Component', 'Qty', 'Cost'])
BoM2 = BoM1.assign(Total=BoM1.Qty*BoM1.Cost).groupby(['Component'],as_index=False).agg({'Qty': 'sum', 'Total': 'sum'})
print(BoM2)
```

Output:

```
    Component  Qty  Total
0  Material 1  1.0    1.0
1  Material 2  4.0    8.0
2  Material 3  6.0   18.0
3  Material 4  4.0   16.0
```

Comment: @Telmo is the code I put in the answer somehow different from yours? It is working fine [here](https://ideone.com/5mEP3X)

Comment: The list is a result of a database query that i transformed into a list like this: BoM = list(BoM), i think that might be the problem.
So the list if not formatted like: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1,2,3,4]]. Instead, it's formatted like [1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]

Comment: So you have a series of individual lists? If so, you need to append them to a master list (what I've called `BoM` in the answer) as you loop over the results from the database, and then input that to the dataframe

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll try to figure it out. Thank you !